# How would one relay a raw tx double spend to a node that accepts it?

Tags: bitcoind, doublespend

All of the pushtx sites reject the tx as a double spend. Would I have to run my own node through bitcoind? How would one do this?

Comment: First of all, could it be indeed a double-spending transaction, and you are not aware of it? (that is, have you tried to spend the same UTXOs before and the transaction haven't got confirmed) Or you are just trying to broadcast a transaction that you know is a double-spent?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have custom software that can broadcast the transaction for you. Basically any and all nodes and transaction broadcast services will fully validate the transaction before it is broadcast. One part of that is checking for double spends, so you will need software that does not do this. AFAIK, there is no publicly available software that does that, so you would need to write your own broadcaster.

Comment: I've been reading around and see that a bitcore.js node can relay non-standard transactions. Is this wrong?

Comment: I don't know as I haven't used bitcore, but non-standard transactions are completely different from double spends. Double spends are not non-standard, they are invalid.

Comment: double-spends are not invalid

Comment: @amaclin well, they are, they violate consensus rules.

Comment: Double spends are only invalid inside a chain (the same output cannot be spent within one chain of blocks). The individual transactions, seen in isolation, are both valid, and preference for one or another is up to individual node's policy. Relaying double spends will not get you banned by the network, as it is not an unambiguous violation of the protocol. Submitting a transaction with an invalid signature for example is.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it - is broadcast the transaction to as many nodes, as possible. You can take my program for it https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2rUa/zgcW6vf8g and add more ip-addresses to .conf file